# MySql update with subselect

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a mysql database table where there is an email column which can contain up to two emails separated by an semicolon. 
What i want to achieve is write the second email address in the email field into another column email2
This is what I tried so far without success:

```
UPDATE user AS u
SET email2 = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, ';', -1)
              FROM user
              WHERE user.id=u.id)
WHERE username LIKE "%;%"
```

When searching for this problems there were some solutions unsing a second subquery within the subquery but none of them really matched my problem.

If anybody has a solution please post it. I have been stuck for at leas 2 hours.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to complicate your life :

```
UPDATE user 
SET email2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, ';', -1) 
WHERE username LIKE '%;%';
```

and to clean first column in same query

```
UPDATE user 
SET 
  email2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, ';', -1),
  email = SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, ';', 1),
WHERE username LIKE '%;%';
```

Comment: hehe, sometimes it is better to step away from the screen and take a few breaths of air :-)

Thank you very much for giving me this simple solution :-)