# MySQL update subselect issue

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Before I post my question, I would like to tell you all, that this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565176/mysql-update-with-subselect) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008063/mysql-subselect-issue), since I do not want to solve a specific issue, but rather I desire to understand one. Reading the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html), I can see two very interesting examples of anomalies regarding subqueries inside an `update` command:

1. `UPDATE t1 SET column2 = (SELECT MAX(column1) FROM t1);`

The error is

> Error 1093 (ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED) SQLSTATE = HY000 Message = "You
>   can't specify target table 'x' for update in FROM clause"

2.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE s1 IN (SELECT s2 FROM t2 ORDER BY s1 LIMIT 1)
```

The error is

> ERROR 1235 (ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_YET) SQLSTATE = 42000 Message = "This
>   version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME
>   subquery'"

Looking at the first example I can tell that updating `column2` of `t1` might or might not change `column1` values, for instance because of triggers or if the columns are the same. However, I wonder why is MySQL throwing an error instead of evaluating the subquery normally, or at least, determining whether it is possible that the subquery's result will be changed by the `update` while the command is running? As about the second example, I really do not understand why MySQL does not support this syntax. I consider these to be MySQL bugs and I wonder whether there is any schedule when they will be fixed.

Comment: If you don't want any help rewriting the queries, what do you expect us to do? We're not privy to MySQL's priorities and schedule.

Comment: I am not expecting anybody anything. I have asked a question, since I believe it is interesting. If anyone knows the answer, then we all will be informed about it. If I will be the one who finds the answer in the future, then I will surely share. The question is admittedly difficult, but interesting.

Comment: @Barmar, I recently had such an issue and solved it, but I was interested to know the reasons.

Comment: Just a guess: because MySQL is a low-cost product, so they don't have the resources to improve things like this.

Comment: My guess is that the reason is political: if they implement such features for MySQL, then who will buy Oracle?

Comment: Anyway, this question isn't really appropriate for SO, which is for practical, answerable questions about programming. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: These limitations are much less annoying than the one where you can't use the same temporary table twice in the same query. I have a hard time imagining what the root cause of that is.

Comment: Can you give me a link about that?

Comment: Second bullet at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: Interesting. I was not aware of that problem. That affects Descartes multiplication. As far as I know, self-joins are allowed though: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/ and you can play with the join conditions. Maybe the same can be achieved, I did not try that.

Comment: Self-joins are allowed with permanent tables, but not with temporary tables.

Comment: Good point. Then, intuitively, a work-around might be to define more equivalent tables with different names. It is quite annoying, I guess.

Comment: Or just use a real table instead of temporary table, although that's only available if the query can't run multiple times concurrently.

Comment: Yes. It was an interesting conversation, thank you for your time. If I find out anything about this issue, I will surely answer my question to reduce the number of mysteries.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is functionally limited DBMS compared to some other DBMS. These limitations mentioned are not being removed by Oracle (the owner of MySQL) due to several reasons. The limitations you mention are documented by MySQL. There are ways around these issues you observe:

Example replacement for 1:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ttt AS SELECT MAX(column1) col1 FROM t1;
UPDATE t1 SET column2 = (SELECT col1 FROM ttt);
```

Example replacement for 2:

```
CREATE VIEW ttt2 AS SELECT s2 FROM t2 ORDER BY s1 LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE s1 IN (SELECT s2 ttt2);
```

(Strangely enough this works while it is syntactically the same...).

Optional: Start using MariaDB (100% backward compatible with MySQL), and contribute in that project. They are fixing some long standing functionality issues.

Comment: He said he's not asking how to rewrite the queries so they work.

Comment: Norbert, I would like to thank you for your answer, however, I have solved my issues with work-arounds. I am interested to know why do these issues exist, as @Barmar suggested in the previous comment.